# Is there a function to modify string (format, bold, center) with Console.Writeline?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, format

I create a file with classic ASP code and it works. Now I want to apply format on my strings (bold, link for example), are there any functions to do this ?
Thanks

```
Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter("REACH.doc")
Dim title As String

title="TITLE"

'''''Here I want to apply bold on title

file.WriteLine(title)

file.Close()
```

Comment: Is this Classic ASP?  It looks more like vb.net.

Comment: lol... yes it seems like .net to me too
What you need to do is write HTML in the .doc file and then you can use your HTML tags to do BOLD and other formatting